# Only One Participant ID in onTurnBasedMatchReceived()

Tags: android, google-play-services

When the other player makes a turn, I am successfully receiving an "onTurnBasedMatchReceived()" update, but in the match details there is sometimes only my own participantId. Without knowing the other player's ParticipantId, I cannot do a takeTurn and pass the ID to the other player. Why do I sometimes not get the other player's ID and sometimes I do?

Comment: How are you "sometimes" getting the other player's id?

Comment: That's what I'm asking! :-P. When I receive the update with the match, it appears that the match isn't immediately updated with all players or something. If I wait until after I take my turn, the player seems to be there at that point. But not immediately after receiving the update.

Answer (score 0):

If you've auto-matched with a random opponent and not taken the first turn yet, then you will only get one Participant Id. Just pass in `null` to `takeTurn()` for the pendingParticipantId field.

Comment: This is after the initial turns are taken. If I grab the participant ID immediately after receiving the update, it's not always there. It seems there's a delay. So I had to start grabbing it just before sending the turn data rather than grabbing it at the beginning of the turn.