# Room.getParticipants() is returning only one participant

Tags: google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

Is it possible for the Room.getParticipants() method to only return 1 participant even after 2 players started a game?

I think i am having this error and i need the participants to know each other ids. I noticed that the Room API doesn´t even have this method on the site:
[https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/Room.html#getParticipantIds()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/Room.html#getParticipantIds%28%29)

Should i use another method? I wanna make one participant have knowledge of another and vice-versa(at least the id of them).

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767373/only-one-participant-id-in-onturnbasedmatchreceived) if you are dealing with turn-based multiplayer.

It appears that `participantID` is consistent in the current match, but not across all matches (or rooms rather).

I'm currently trying to debug my own real-time multiplayer app, so I am still new as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when i saved the Room instance after it's creation (in onRoomCreated() listener method). Instead of this you should save Room instance after it is connected, i.e. in onRoomConnected() method:

```
//Room instance var
private Room mRoom;

//method of RoomUpdateListener
@Override
public void onRoomConnected(int i, Room room)
{   
    mRoom = room;
    ...
}

// get partcipants after rom is connected will return have the right size
mRoom.getParticipants()
```